# Multiple apps in a single parse server

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification, parse-server

I worked all week to migrate my apps hosted on parse.com to parse server, managed to make everything work perfectly, the only problem is to get it to run multiple apps on a single hardware, without my having to allocate a server app for that it has, it would become expensive.

I read this [discussion](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/pull/263) about it, and on this basis, follow the following solution:

```
var app1 = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'myAppId1',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'myMasterKey1', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/parse',  // Don't forget to change to https if needed
  push: pushConfig,
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ["Posts", "Comments"] // List of classes to support for query subscriptions
  }
});

var app2 = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/app2',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'myAppId2',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'myMasterKey2', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/parse',  // Don't forget to change to https if needed
  push: pushConfig,
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ["Posts", "Comments"] // List of classes to support for query subscriptions
  }
});
// Client-keys like the javascript key or the .NET key are not necessary with parse-server
// If you wish you require them, you can set them as options in the initialization above:
// javascriptKey, restAPIKey, dotNetKey, clientKey

var app = express();

// Serve static assets from the /public folder
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

// Serve the Parse API on the /parse URL prefix
var mountPath = process.env.PARSE_MOUNT || '/parse';
app.use(mountPath, app1);
app.use(mountPath, app2);
```

This works until the time test environment can use multiple apps for sending push on the same hardware, just creating multiple instances of the server parse pointing to different database.

Can anyone tell me if something could go wrong with the apps in production?
This would cause me a problem in the future?

Someone supports this solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Parse Server as of v2.2.9 **doesn't** offer multi-app support.

It requires individual instances (and mount paths) for each app. You would otherwise run into complications regarding cloud code as the core is not designed for multi-app support although it carries some legacy from Parse.com like the `appId` property which would be a step towards it.

However since it is now an open source project it may offer multi-app support in the future.

### Update

Parse server v2.2.18 still does only supports one single app per instance, according to the [wiki](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Compatibility-with-Hosted-Parse#single-app-aware):

> Parse Server only supports single app instances. There is ongoing work
> to make Parse Server multi-app aware. However, if you intend to run
> many different apps with different datastores, you currently would
> need to instantiate separate instances.

Comment: After some research time, made some changes in the code and atualemente'm running a single instance of Parsi-server with multiple apps tied to it, I did several tests and everything seems to behave as it should, I will continue to test and put some apps in production to see if it continues to work free from any problem.

Comment: @jucajl That sounds good, maybe you want to join the discussion over at github and eventually make a pull request with the official repository. There have been many discussions and seemingly already working code proposals for multi-app support. However the dev community couldn't agree on a concept for different reasons, e.g. security or core complexity.

Comment: @jucajl Can you please share how you did it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `PM2` and launch 2 instances of Parse Server. Here's how `PM2` config file would look like:

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "app1",
      "script": "servers/app1/server.js",
      "cwd": "/home/parse",
      "log_file": "logs/server-app1.log",
      "error_file": "logs/server-app1-error.log",
      "log_date_format": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z",
      "instances": 1,
      "merge_logs": true,
      "watch": ["/usr/bin/parse-server", "/home/parse/servers/app1"],
      "ignore_watch": ["logs"],
      "env": {"VERBOSE": true}
    },
    {
      "name": "app2",
      "script": "servers/app2/server.js",
      "cwd": "/home/parse",
      "log_file": "logs/server-app2.log",
      "error_file": "logs/server-app2-error.log",
      "log_date_format": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z",
      "instances": 1,
      "merge_logs": true,
      "watch": ["/usr/bin/parse-server", "/home/parse/servers/app2"],
      "ignore_watch": ["logs"],
      "env": {"VERBOSE": true}
    },
    {
      "name": "parse-dashboard",
      "script": "/usr/bin/parse-dashboard",
      "args": "--config dashboard/parse-dashboard-config.json  --mountPath /dashboard",
      "cwd": "/home/parse",
      "log_file": "logs/dashboard.log",
      "error_file": "logs/dashboard-error.log",
      "log_date_format": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z",
      "instances": 1,
      "watch": ["/usr/bin/parse-dashboard"]
    }
  ]
}
```