# Push Notification - Two apps sharing the same Parse Serve

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

Issue Description

My two apps (a free app and a pro app) point to the same parse database.

Expected Results

I want Push Notifications working in both two apps.

Actual Outcome

While for now, only one app can send push notification successfully.

Steps to reproduce

Besides sending notifications by my apps, I also tried to send push by dashboard.
The result is same, only one app works, another fails to get the notification.

Environment Setup

I'm trying the way in Github [#2188](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/2188).
I also refer to following two links:
https://www.parse.com/questions/push-to-multiple-apps
[Multiple apps in a single parse server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37077737/multiple-apps-in-a-single-parse-server)

But all didn't work.

Thanks so much for helping out.

My cloud code in index.js are:

- { }`push: { ios: [

  { pfx: __dirname+'/push_certs/DevPushLoveAgainPro.p12', // Dev PFX or P12 
  bundleId: 'com.app1', 
  production: false // Dev },

  { pfx: __dirname+'/push_certs/ApplePushLoveAgainPro.p12', // Prod PFX or P12 
  bundleId: 'com.app1', 
  production: true // Prod }, 
  { pfx: __dirname+'/push_certs/DevPushLoveAgainFree.p12', // Prod PFX or P12 
  bundleId: 'com.app2', 
  production: false // Prod },

  { pfx: __dirname+'/push_certs/ApplePushLoveAgainFree.p12', // Prod PFX or P12 
  bundleId: 'com.app2', 
  production: true // Prod } ] }`

  ---

  Parse.Cloud.define("push", function(request, response) 
  {
  var id = request.params.toUser;
  getUser(id).then
  (
      function(user)
      {
              var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
              query.equalTo("user", user);
              Parse.Push.send({
                where: query,
                data: request.params.data
              }, {
               useMasterKey: true,
                success: function() {
                  response.success('Success!!!!!!!!!!!');
                },
                error: function(error) {
                   response.error('Error!!!!!!!!!!!!!! ' + error.message);
                }
          });

  ```
  }
  ,
  function(error)
  {
      response.error(error);
  }
  ```

  );});function getUser(userId){
  var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  userQuery.equalTo("objectId", userId);
  return userQuery.first
  ({
      useMasterKey: true,
      success: function(userRetrieved)
      {
          return userRetrieved;
      },
      error: function(error)
      {
          return error;
      }
  });
  };

Comment: Did you check if the Installation collection (in parse-dashboard) contain entries of both bundle identifiers?

Comment: @RanHassid, thanks so much for replying. What do you mean by 'contain entries of both bundle identifiers' ? My two apps share the same parse db, and I can save data successfully.

Comment: Under your installation collection you should see which app is registered.. there you need to make sure that both app are registered

Comment: @RanHassid, sorry, I'm using SaShiDo; I can see data from 2 apps in db with different appIdentifiers.

Comment: So i think the issue is with your certificate..

Comment: @RanHassid， thanks so much for replying. I double checked my certificate, nothing wrong. Anything else I can check? I also checked with SaShiDo's support, no meaning reply yet.

Comment: @RanHassid, hello?

Comment: Can you please try to do it one by one? First use the first certificate only and check if it works and then try to switch to use the second one.. also can you please add also your client side code and how you are sending the push ?

Comment: @RanHassid,  yes, I used to test certificate one by one, but seems my certs settings in index.js doesn't work. I have already uploaded all certs for two apps on SaShiDo's Dashboard. Can we talk on Skype or iMessage? so that communication will be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

So, at here, when we generate p12 files from KeyChain, we shouldn't involve the private key, even you don't add password.
So just ignore the private key when generating p12 files.